# How to create SOAP web service Stub using wsimpot command

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, wsimport

I have .wsdl file downloaded from a webservice. I want to create Stub using wsimport command with the wsdl file. I have tried below commands and non of those worked.

```
wsimport -d . -wsdllocation downloaded.wsdl -keep

wsimport -d . -wsdllocation C:\downloaded.wsdl -keep
```

#### error message is

Missing WSDL_URI

Comment: Try using the forward slash.  wsimport -d  .  c:/downloaded.wsdl -keep

Comment: @ArnabDhar - I have tried that. Still getting the same error

Comment: wsimport -keep -wsdllocation=META-INF/wsdl/MyService.wsdl. Hope you are not missing the =

Comment: @ArnabDhar - unrecognized parameter -wsdllocation=downloaded.wsdl error this time.